# Is there any Apache shutdown hook to be used for cleanup?

Tags: apache2

I am currently developing a module for Apache 2/2.2 and need to perform some cleanup before the main Apache process terminates (not the child processes).

I have searched extensively without finding any guidelines on which hook to use. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know, however I'm intereste to know what it is you are devloping which would requie this?

Comment: I was thinking about forking off a separate process on startup and would like to be able to notify this to shutdown when the main Apache process terminates so that their life cycles align.

Comment: Although I have not been able to find a suitable hook to use, I have found a potential workaround. It may be possible to add a cleanup function to the server or process pool, which would then be called when the pool is deleted as the process terminates. Does anyone know if this would trigger when the main Apache process terminates or just when the children terminates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are exactly trying to do, but I think that the apr_reslist_create and apr_pool_cleanup_register functions may help you. One of the parameters in the apr_reslist_create function is apr_reslist_destructor which you can use to pass destructor function. Also, I think you should take a look at the mod_dbd module source code since it is a pretty good example of how to create and cleanup external resources from the apache process.

[Apr-Util apr_reslist_create](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr-util/1.3/group___a_p_r___util___r_l.html#g608ebcddce542603a7f1d3cf51ae8d3c)

[Apr apr_pool_cleanup_register](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.3/group___pool_cleanup.html#g6bdb28224dfe08160cbe3ba6b22dcbd7)

Comment: Where would I call apr_pool_cleanup_register? I am trying to create a connection to a msg broker and want to connect on server start and destroy resources on server shut down.

Comment: You can call it from the child_init hook function. First add a hook with the ap_hook_child_init(my_module_child_init_fn, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE) call, then create your resource and setup apr_pool_cleanup_register inside of the my_module_child_init_fn function.

Comment: Awesome thank you. So then my connection will also last the entire time the process is alive and as soon as the process is killed then the cleanup function will be called, correct?

Comment: That is almost correct. Your cleanup function will be invoked when the apr pool gets destroyed. You are basically attaching a cleanup call to your process pool.